Upload images flutter with json data
request is working in post



how to send same request in flutter using Dio package
have tried
    formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "mobileRequest": {
        "companyRequest": {
          "companyId": 1,
          "serviceName": "service1",
          "serviceDescription": "service1",
          "serviceContactInfo": "+201001656577,+20100987654",
          "serviceCategoryId": 1
        }
      },
    });
    for (var file in filePathes) {
      formData.files.addAll([
        MapEntry(
          "files",
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            file,
            filename: file.split('/').last,
          ),
        ),
      ]);
    }

but response is 500 internal server error
and also tried
 List<MultipartFile> filesList2 = serviceEntiti.images!
        .map((e) => MultipartFile.fromFileSync(e.path))
        .toList();
  formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "mobileRequest": {
        "companyRequest": {
          "companyId": 1,
          "serviceName": "service1",
          "serviceDescription": "service1",
          "serviceContactInfo": "+201001656577,+20100987654",
          "serviceCategoryId": 1
        }
      },
      "files": filesList2,
    });

but also get the same response 500 internal server error

Try this:
try {
  // Prepare the JSON data
  final jsonData = {
    "mobileRequest": {
      "companyRequest": {
        "companyId": 1,
        "serviceName": "service1",
        "serviceDescription": "service1",
        "serviceContactInfo": "+201001656577,+20100987654",
        "serviceCategoryId": 1
      }
    }
  };

  // Prepare the FormData
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(photo.path, filename: 'photo'),
    'json': jsonEncode(jsonData), // Add the JSON data as a string
  });

  const url = 'https://your-url.com/endpoint';

  final response = await _dio.post(
    url,
    data: formData,
    onSendProgress: (count, total) {
      int percentage = (count / total * 100).toInt();
      print("progress: $percentage");
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("success");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} on DioException catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Failed to upload photo: ${e.error}');
} catch (e) {
  print('Error uploading photo: $e');
  throw Exception(e);
}


